# UITableViewCell didTransitionToState Not Redrawing nonvisible cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I currently have a UITableView that contains editable UITableViewCells.  When a cell goes into edit mode, i use the willTransitionToState and didTransitionToState to show/hide a UITextField when the cell goes into edit mode.  The problem, is if I have invisible cells, the willTransitionToState/didTransitionToState does not get called when they become visible... so the cells still look like they are in edit mode.  Does anyone have a suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding/unhiding subviews of your UITableViewCell do not constitute a change of state, that's why those methods don't get called.

Depending on your implementation, you could invoke those methods yourself when hiding/unhiding. But in general, you should implement the hiding/unhiding logic in those methods, not outside of them, e.g. a change of state leads to the change of the subviews, not vice versa.

For more concrete answers you should provide samples of your code and get more concrete on what you are trying to achieve.

Peter

Comment: I figured out my answer!  I'm wondering if this is a bug though with Apple's SDK.  Thanks for your input!